# Push files to GitHub from NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, git, github, push

I have a NodeJS server which is generating a server-side JS code into a separate folder on the server and then serves it to the user as a .zip file. I would like to be able to take this code and push it to a GitHub repository the user would specify (or even better- create a new brunch and push it to the branch). I was checking GitHub API but I could not find an  endpoint, which would describe this situation. I also checked one node module, but the same story- no information about if this is possible (and how) or not.

My question is- Is it possible to take a folder on a server and push it to a GitHub repo (if all the credentials and keys are known) programatically and if so, can anyone please direct me to some resources? I tried to find something but nothing was relevant.

Thank you,
T.

Comment: You don't need the GitHub API; just use git itself.

Comment: something like this: http://www.nodegit.org/#Push ?

Comment: Check out http://www.nodegit.org/api/remote/#push

Answer (score 5):

I've just found these two libraries, that can help you to push your files to git from Node.js:

- [git-js](https://github.com/steveukx/git-js) is a lightweight wrapper around installed `git` binary
- [nodegit](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit) is a standalone Git client implementation in Node.js

Just use the provided API programmatically to commit and push files. You could create a separate branch if you want and tag your commits.

Answer (score 0):

just install git bash and do it through that. I don't use anything but the terminal to do my git repos. good luck.