# How to push a directory from NodeJs to Git (GitHub)

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github, push

**I have a NodeJs server that generates a few files, I need to push these files automatically to a git repository (GitHub to be specific).**

[**The same question has been asked here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074298/push-files-to-github-from-nodejs-server) but it is old, and does not really have an answer or some basic example.

**What I have searched and found out so far:**

- A lot of blogs online suggested using **Git Bash**, but none of them showed any examples, and I'm new to NodeJS and have never used it in a NodeJs server.
- There is something like **NodeGit** [[Website](https://www.nodegit.org/)] [[GitHub](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit)], to me it seemed mostly focus on pulling data from git and the examples of pushing a specific directory from the NodeJs directory were rather vague or a little bit hard for me to understand.
  [Link to the NodeGit #Push Documentation](https://www.nodegit.org/api/remote/#push)
- There's also **git-js** [[GitHub](https://github.com/steveukx/git-js)], which I also lacked to understand how to push a specific directory or folder. Some example from the docs: `.push(remote, branch[, options])`

Comment: What's the purpose of these files?  In general, you shouldn't check generated files into a repository.

Comment: @bk2204 Just a few JSON files that get pushed to GitHub, then to Netlify which generates a JamStack / Static Site with a site generator based on the content from the JSON files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do somithing similar to :

```
require('child_process').execFile('git', ['commit', '-am', 'xxx']);
```

or

```
require('child_process').execFile('git', ['push']);
```

or

```
require('child_process').execFile('sh', ['-c', 'git commit -am xxx && git push']);
```

no dependencies, low fail probability :)

see more here :
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback